# ORACLE SQL Joining tables based on different time based events

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables:

- PROCESSOR_EVENT(Id, Time, Machine, Name, State)
- COMM_EVENT(Id, Time, Machine, Name, Type)

I want to retrieve the difference between PROCESSOR_EVENT.Time and the next COMM_EVENT in time that is before the next PROCESSOR_EVENT.Time.

i.e. First COMM_EVENT event after a PROCESSOR_EVENT that occurs before the next PROCESSOR_EVENT.

**Example data:**

```
PROCESSOR_EVENT(Id, Time, Machine, Name, State)
1, 01:00:00, TRX4, Ignition, Heated
2, 01:00:03, TRX1, Movement, Triangulating
3, 01:00:23, TRX4, Movement, Heated
4, 01:00:32, TRX4, Direction Change, Stable
5, 01:00:56, TRX4, Stopping, Heated

COMM_EVENT(Id, Time, Machine, Name, Type)
1, 01:00:02, TRX4, Direction request, Request
2, 01:00:15, TRX4, Direction acknowledgement, Acknowledgement
3, 01:00:16, TRX1, Position change, Command
4, 01:00:34, TRX4, Direction request, Request
5, 01:01:02, TRX4, Position change, Command
```

**Expected return:**

```
PROCESSOR_EVENT.Time, PROCESSOR_EVENT.Machine, PROCESSOR_EVENT.Name, COMM_EVENT.Time, COMM_EVENT.Type, TimeDifference
01:00:00, TRX4, Ignition, 01:00:02, Request, 2
01:00:03, TRX1, Movement, 01:00:16, Command, 13
01:00:23, TRX4, Movement, null, null, null
01:00:32, TRX4, Direction Change, 01:00:34, Request, 11
01:00:56, TRX4, Stopping, 01:01:02, Command, 6
```

Any ideas on how to go about doing that would be great, thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: You can try it with lag and lead functions.

Comment: In your expected return shouldn't processor event 4 be coupled with comm event 4? And no corresponding comm event for processor event 3? You said you want the next comm event before the next processor event. There is no comm event that occurs after processor event 3 but before the next processor event (which is 4). Right?

Comment: Yup you're right, thanks for pointing that out, I've updated it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(t.Time, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS "PROCESSOR_EVENT.Time",
  t.Machine AS "PROCESSOR_EVENT.Machine",
  t.Name AS "PROCESSOR_EVENT.Name",
  TO_CHAR(t.ce_time, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS "COMM_EVENT.Time",
  t.ce_type AS "COMM_EVENT.Type",
  (t.ce_time - t.Time)*24*60*60 AS TimeDifference
FROM (
  SELECT pe.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pe.ID ORDER BY ce.Time) AS rn,
    ce.Time AS ce_time,
    ce.Type AS ce_type
  FROM (
    SELECT PROCESSOR_EVENT.*,
      LEAD(Time) OVER (PARTITION BY Machine ORDER BY Time) AS next_pe_time
    FROM PROCESSOR_EVENT
    -- here put WHERE with filtering conditions for PROCESSOR_EVENT table
  ) pe
  LEFT OUTER JOIN COMM_EVENT ce
    ON ce.Machine = pe.Machine
    AND ce.Time > pe.Time
    AND (pe.next_pe_time IS NULL OR ce.Time < pe.next_pe_time)
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
ORDER BY t.Time
```

Test it on [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5da61/27)

Comment: Hmm that looked promising but I'm getting this error:
ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery
01799. 00000 -  "a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery"

Comment: @RichardMaguire see rewritten query it works as expected

Comment: Thanks @Rimas I'm close to getting it to run I think.

I'm not sure but is the syntax of your JOINs Oracle friendly? I had to change "LEFT JOIN" to "LEFT OUTER JOIN" otherwise it would crash. But I'm not sure what to turn "JOIN" (Line 18) into?

And finally, the size of PROCESSOR_EVENT and COMM_EVENT is quite large, about a million records each, if I want to only query results between certain date & time ranges, where would I insert that restriction in your query?

Comment: Ok thank you. What about the "JOIN" on line 18, is that a LEFT, RIGHT, INNER or FULL join?

Comment: @RichardMaguire I simplified query (now only one `JOIN`). I think it's cleaner and more understandable now. I have marked location where to put filtering conditions.

Comment: Thank you! With a tiny bit of tweaking (it needed another WHERE after the LEFT OUTER JOIN) it works really well! Thanks a lot for your help @Rimas :)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to approach this problem.  Here is an approach that uses `lead()` multiple times, after doing a union of the two tables.  The basic data is:

```
select pc.*,
       lead(time) over (partition by machine order by time) as nexttime,
       lead(which) over (partition by machine order by time) as nextwhich,
       lead(type) over (partition by machine order by time) as nexttype
from (select pe.time, pe.machine, pe.machine, pe.name, 'pe' as which
      from processor_event pe
      union all
      select ce.time, ce.machine, ce.name, 'ce' as which
      from comm_event ce
     ) pc;
```

Next, we just need to apply the logic that you want to this data:

```
with pc as (
      select pc.*,
             lead(time) over (partition by machine order by time) as nexttime,
             lead(which) over (partition by machine order by time) as nextwhich,
             lead(type) over (partition by machine order by time) as nexttype
      from (select pe.time, pe.machine, pe.name, NULL as type, 'pe' as which
            from processor_event pe
            union all
            select ce.time, ce.machine, ce.name, ce.type, 'ce' as which
            from comm_event ce
           ) pc
     )
select pc.time, pc.machine, pc.name,
       (case when nextwhich = 'ce' then nexttime end) as comm_time,
       (case when nextwhich = 'ce' then nexttype end) as comm_type,
       ((case when nextwhich = 'ce' then nexttime end) - time) as diff
from pc
where pc.which = 'pe';
```

Comment: Woah, I haven't done SQL that advanced before. Is that all 1 query?

Comment: @Richard Maguire: Yes, one query. The first query starting with SELECT and ending wth a semicolon is the base statement. Just for illustration. Execute it to see what LEAD and UNION ALL do. The real query contains this base statement. It starts with WITH and ends with a semicolon.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks Thorsten. I tried to execute the first query but get the error:
ORA-00904: "TYPE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
Error at Line: 4 Column: 12

Comment: In that last 'select' statement `select pe.time, pe.machine, pe.name` is that meant to be `pc.time, pc.time, pc.machine`?